# Beautifulsoup python Howlongtobeat.com extracting elements and export to .csv

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is what I have so far:

```
from requests import get



url = 'https://howlongtobeat.com/game.php?id=38050'

response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

game_name = html_soup.select('div.profile_header')[0].text
game_length = html_soup.select('div.game_times li div')[-1].text
game_developer = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nDeveloper:\n')[0].next_sibling
game_publisher = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nPublisher:\n')[0].next_sibling
game_console = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nPlayable On:\n')[0].next_sibling
game_genres = html_soup.find_all('strong', string='\nGenres:\n')[0].next_sibling

print(game_name)
print(game_length)
print(game_developer)
print(game_publisher)
print(game_console)
print(game_genres)
```

this outputs:

```
God of War (2018) 
31 Hours 

SIE Santa Monica Studio 

Sony Interactive Entertainment 

PlayStation 4 

Third-Person, Action, Adventure
```

Planning on making a spreadsheet on with this data (once I figure out how to extract Name of the game, Main + Extras game length, Developer's Name, Publisher, Playable On, and Genre fields)

so it would store this data, I think it should print the data like this before I can store it:

```
God of War (2018) 
31 Hours 
SIE Santa Monica Studio
Sony Interactive Entertainment
PlayStation 4
Third-Person, Action, Adventure
```

any help would be appreciated

Edit ---

I've done a little research and I think I need Pandas

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can remove the trailing spaces applying `strip()` on your string.
After that you can create a csv file where to store you your data as df:

```
f = open(path_where_to_save + 'info.csv', 'a')
f.write(str(game_name)+ ',' + str(game_length) + ',' + str(game_developer))
f.close()
```

Note the `a` in `open` which appends instead of overwrite the first line